# famo.us: what is the meaning of the "deploy" function in famo.us?

Tags: famo.us

I've seen examples where people subclass the `Surface` class in famo.us and they override the `deploy` function.  Is that a special function that famo.us needs on renderables?  I have a 
"control" that I am building and it has certain animations that I want to show when it becomes visible, but I don't want them to start when I instantiate the object I want them to be shown later when it is shown to the user.  Is this what the `deploy` function is for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclosure: I am probably the author of many of those examples you have seen overriding deploy.

When I was working with Famo.us and needed to add my own attributes to native DOM elements, I came about the deploy function in Surface. Deploy takes a target element that it receives from the ElementAllocator which is managing the DOM resources. This is the Surface's chance to alter any of the original DOM element's attributes to fit the options supplied to Surface.

To answer your question, The deploy function only really needs to be overridden if you need to access the original DOM element right before it gets shown on screen. You however only need to set the opacity of an element and may do so using surfaces on 'deploy' event.

Here is the example using an event..

```
var Engine          = require('famous/core/Engine');
var Surface         = require('famous/core/Surface');
var StateModifier   = require('famous/modifiers/StateModifier');

var context = Engine.createContext();

var surface = new Surface({
    size:[200,200],
    content:"Hello!",
    properties: {
        backgroundColor:'green',
        color:'white',
        textAlign:'center',
        lineHeight:'200px'
    }
})

surface.on('deploy',function(){
    console.log("Deployed!");
    surface.state.setOpacity(1);
})

surface.state = new StateModifier({ origin:[0.5,0.5]});

surface.state.setOpacity(0);

context.add(surface.state).add(surface);
```

While using the deploy event, you can also see something quite interesting. If you reload your code via the web console, or grunt, and the Famo.us app is not the currently visible tab, the deploy function will not be called. This is a function of requestAnimationFrame that allows it to not spend cycles updating a screen that is not visible. When you finally open the tab, you can see "Deployed!" gets logged to the console.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about overriding the deploy method, but I think what you're looking for is the 'deploy' event.

The 'deploy' event is indeed triggered when the surface is added to the live dom.  So for code you want to run after the surface is in the dom tree:

```
var surface = new Surface({content: 'foo'})
surface.on('deploy', function() {
   // your code that requires surface to be in the dom
});
```

I'm not a famo.us dev, so this isn't an 'official' answer, but I did see this in the source and have started using it and it works.

Source:https://github.com/Famous/core/blob/35461b36c8d09d39e96c3d61ebd7908946d3f668/Surface.js#L451